# TypeError: Object of type 'Response' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, forms, flask

The function `extract_data()` converts uploaded PDF file to JSON data.

Function `form_input()` is meant to post the JSON data from "extract_data" as default input form values.

**`Extract_data()` generates JSON data but is not redirecting it to `form_input()`**

Below are the functions -

```
from flask import render_template, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def extract_data(input_module=pdftotext):
  if request.method == "POST":
    file = request.files["file"]
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        invoicefile = secure_filename(file.filename)
        extracted_str = input_module.to_text(invoicefile)
        json_data=jsonify(ext)
        session['json_data'] = json_data
        return redirect(url_for('form_input', json_data=json_data)
  return render_template("extract.html")
```

Here is extract.html

```
    <html>
     <form method='POST' enctype=multipart/form-data>
        <input type="file" name="file" class="btn btn-success"></input>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" value=Upload class="btn btn-warning">Go! 
   </button>
      </form>
   </html>
```

The function `form_input()` is meant to get the `json_data` from `extract_data()` and use it as default form input values.

```
@app.route("/form_input")
def form_input():
  json_data = request.args['json_data']
  json_data = session['json_data']
  if request.method == 'POST':
     submited_item =  request.POST['%s' % (value1)]
  return render_template("inputdata.html", json_data="json_data")
```

Here is `input_data.html`:

```
<html>


<form method="POST">{{ csrf_token }}
    <label>Input data</label>  
    <input type="text">

    {% for item in json_data %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="{{ item.value1 }}" value="{{ item.value1 }}"> {{ item.value1 }}<br>
    {% endfor %}

  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

</html>
```

Comment: please fix your indentation

Comment: @gogaz ..done..:)

Comment: What is not working ? is that because first form's `action` is not set ?

Comment: the first form is generating the json data..but i am not able to receive that in 2nd form